# How to convert .tem file into gif

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to upload file (image) and use it as transparent

I am getting following path

```
C:\Windows\Temp\php30C.tmp
```

But it’s not recognizing file as gif.

My question is how to convert C:\Windows\Temp\php30C.tmp into the original file format,

best regards,

Comment: i don't see how this is related to javascript, nevertheless, is the file opening as an image file in the computer?

Comment: How are you handling the upload? is it through php? i think you forgot to `move_uploaded_file` ...

Comment: no just html code. and php for $gotimage=$_FILES['pfilename']['tmp_name']; path @LatheesanKanes

Comment: tmp is a temporary file, you could try just renaming the xxx.tmp to xxx.gif but often tmp is temporary as it is not a full file, maybe 1/2 downloaded etc.

Comment: @DeanMeehan can i get original path of the file....its make my work easy...?

Comment: No, that's like asking if someone placed a file on my usb drive, do I know where the file came from. That data isn't stored in the file unfortunately.

Comment: ok thanks @DeanMeehan can you recommend me any javascirpt can fill data from input file to hidden field...

Comment: I've never actually worked with file upload before in Javascript, you'd be better researching how to achieve this. Best of Luck! :)